# Identify this derivation of PI

Tags: integration, pi

The book "Build supercomputers with Raspberry PI" (C. Morrison) calculates a numerical approximation of PI using the following integral:

$${\pi} = \int_{0}^1 \frac{4}{1+x^2}\ dx $$

Who is credited with this derivation? I could not find it among the named formulas (Euler, Ramanujan, etc) for calculating PI.

Comment: That's probably because the integral is really easy to calculate. The integrand is continuous over $[0,1]$, hence has an antiderivative on that interval, namely $4\arctan(x)$. The result follows.

Comment: Analytically it is trivial, but it is used numerically, to calculate digits of PI.

Comment: Wait... so what exactly are you looking for then? Did I answer your question?

Comment: You sort of did... I have to presume it has no "name" if the book and this form both don't have a name for it.

Comment: Numerical source for those who may be interested! https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Build-Supercomputers-with-Raspberry-Pi-3/blob/master/Chapter02/03_MPI_08_b.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of things in mathematics are nameless, and this formula is one of them. As discussed in comments, the antiderivative of the integrand is simply $4\tan^{-1}x$, and substituting $x=1$ and simplifying gives $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8-...., x^2 \le 1$$
Integrate w,r, t, x you get the famos Newton-Gregory series
$$\tan^{-1} x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+,,,,,$$
Which has been helping in computing the value of $\pi$ $(x=1)$correct to several thousand decimal places to if any string pf numbers repeats to decide if $\pi$ is a rational number.
But $\pi$ every time turns out to be irrational.

Comment: I have seen $\pi/4=1-1/3+1/5-1/7+...$ called Gregory's Series. It would take about $10^{1000}$ terms to get $\pi$ to $1000$ decimal places. But we have $\pi/4=\tan^{-1}(1/2)+\tan^{-1}(1/3)=2\tan^{-1}(1/3)+\tan^{-1}(1/7)$ because $\tan^{-1}a+\tan^{-1}b=\tan^{-1}((a+b)/(1-ab))$ when $a,b>0$ and $ab<1.$